# Lyapunov functions and stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let's consider a differential equations system 
$$\begin{cases}
x' = -xy^4 \\
y' = yx^4
\end{cases}.$$

One of the solutions of the following system
$$\begin{cases}
0 = -xy^4 \\
0 = yx^4
\end{cases}$$
is $P =(x_0, y_0) = (0, 0)$.

I know that if $(x_0, y_0)$ is a stationary point and $V(x_0, y_0)$ is a Lyapunov function that is

1. $V(x_0, y_0) = 0$ and $V(x, y) > 0$ for $(x, y) \neq (x_0, y_0)$,
2. $\big<\nabla V(x, y), [-xy^4, yx^4]^{T} \big> \, \le 0$

then $(x_0, y_0)$ is a stable point.

Let's consider a function $V(x, y) = x^{\alpha} + y^{\alpha}, \quad \alpha > 0$. I am to show that for some $\alpha$, $V(x_0, y_0)$ is a Lyapunov function.

Is obvious that if $\alpha = 2$ for example property $1$ follows immediately. However I have some problems with showing the second one. We get
$$\big<[2x, 2y], [-xy^4, yx^4]^{T} \big> \\
= -2x^2y^2(y-x)(y+x).$$

If we consider $x = 2$ and $y = 1$ then
$$\big<[2x, 2y], [-xy^4, yx^4]^{T} \big> = 12 > 0.$$

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you take $\alpha=4$ you get the directional derivative equal zero. That means that $V$ is not just some Lyapunov function but it is a first integral of your system. The orbits are level sets of such $V$ which are (sort of) circles. $(0,0)$ is stable but not asymptotically stable.